# What is the proper way to make a bash script portable between Linux and FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd

I am working on some bash scripts that I'd like to work across my Linux and FreeBSD systems.

Since I mostly work in Linux, I am used to starting my bash scripts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

But this doesn't work on FreeBSD since bash lives at `/usr/local/bin/bash`. So on FreeBSD my scripts need to start with

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

**So is there something else I could use that would be portable across both systems?** I'd rather not maintain two versions of the scripts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

should do the trick, provided that bash is on the path somewhere. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) for more details.

Comment: Ah thanks. I'd heard the same thing from a grumpy sysadmin who is generally just mad at me for ever exposing him to anything not FreeBSD, so I just wanted to check against the community.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, if you want portability, invoke as /bin/sh and code to POSIX.  It's less pretty, but you will run into fewer potential issues if you do.

Comment: Alternatively, choose a more complete language, possibly perl, if sh is too limited.

Comment: Although, for the record: /bin/sh is often not a POSIX shell. Essentially every modern system ships with a POSIX shell, but (eg on Solaris), for compatibility with old scripts, /bin/sh is left as the old, pre-POSIX shell. Finding bash by name (with /usr/bin/env), but then not using any bashisms, is a good way of making sure your script runs in a POSIX shell. However, not all systems (eg BSD) come with bash. There is no perfect hashbang that will get you a POSIX shell on all unix systems, sadly, so those of us who have to write scripts that run on every platform have to use some magic...

Answer (score 2):

Use `#!/bin/sh` on both systems if you want to be portable and avoid bashisms entirely.